# Angular *ngFor bound to observable with async pipe - whats happening?

Tags: angular, asynchronous, pipe, ngfor

I have just started with angular4 and have came up against a conceptual problem. The `async` pipe (used in combination with `*ngFor` in this case) is meant to subscribe to an observable and do away with manual subscriptions. Looking at examples on the web:

Case 1: Binding to an observable that contains single items such as `Observable<User>`

Case 2: Binding to an observable that contains arrays of items such as 
`Observable<User[]>`

Case 3: Variations of 1 and 2 with Subject, Promise or BehaviourSubject

(example of case 1 single item: http://briantroncone.com/?p=623)

(example of case 2 array: http://www.concretepage.com/angular-2/angular-2-async-pipe-example)

Conceptually I get that the `ngFor` iterates over an enumerable and I'm assuming that the enumerable is the item emitted from the `Observable` and not the observable itself.

So *ngFor="let user of users" is only going to work on an `Observable<User[]>` and not an `Observable<User>`?

The `*ngFor` is triggered as each item arrives from the observable?

If this is the case then how can we bind to an `Observable` of `Item` and not `Item[]`, how does ngFor iterate over Item when its not an enumerable? Thanks.

Comment: If you want just one item and list is always the same, use this `itemName` in template. Like you meantioned ***ngFor** is only for array not items. Also subscribe work with **Async** so you have to wait for the call to finish. https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you are trying to achieve? Are you trying to ngFor over an object's properties? Or something else?

Answer (score 0):

> *ngFor="let user of users" is only going to work on an `Observable<User[]>` and not an `Observable<User>`?

Yes, `NgFor` directive will create a template once per item from an **iterable**. see **[description](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf#description)** of NgFor. So **`Iterable` not `Object`**.

> The  *ngFor is triggered as each item arrives from the observable?

No, while using observable, `NgFor` will work when observable emit value(entire iterable not pre item of it).

> how does ngFor iterate over Item when its not an enumerable?

Since `ngFor` only supports `Iterable`, so you can create a Pipe converting Object to `Array` by `Object.values` or `Object.keys` so that `ngFor` can iterate.